# How do I apply a replace to each array element in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, replace, preg-replace, str-replace

I have an array with a list of all controllers in my application:

```
$controllerlist = glob("../controllers/*_controller.php");
```

How do I strip `../controllers/` at the start and `_controller.php` at the end of each array element **with one PHP command?**

Comment: Show us the input array and the output array. Right now it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I thought it was quite clear, the input array would be something like `array('../controllers/test_controller.php', '../controllers/hello_controller.php');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As preg_replace can act on an array, you could do:

```
$array = array(
    "../controllers/test_controller.php",
    "../controllers/hello_controller.php",
    "../controllers/user_controller.php"
);

$array = preg_replace('~../controllers/(.+?)_controller.php~', "$1", $array);
print_r($array);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => test
    [1] => hello
    [2] => user
)
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for regex in this case unless there can be variations of what you mentioned.

```
$array = array(
    "../controllers/test_controller.php",
    "../controllers/hello_controller.php",
    "../controllers/user_controller.php"
);

// Actual one liner..
$list = str_replace(array('../controllers/', '_controller.php'), "", $array);

var_dump($array);
```

This will output

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'test' (length=4)
  1 => string 'hello' (length=5)
  2 => string 'user' (length=4)
```

Which is (I think) what you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

Mapping one array to another:

```
$files = array(
  '../controllers/test_controller.php',
  '../controllers/hello_controller.php'
);
$start = strlen('../controllers/');
$end = strlen('_controller.php') * -1;

$controllers = array_map(
  function($value) use ($start, $end) {
    return substr($value, $start, $end);
  },
  $files
);
var_dump($controllers);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you defined "command", but I doubt there is a way to do that with one simple function call.

However, if you're simply wanting it to be compact, here's a simple way of doing it:

```
$controllerlist = explode('|||', str_replace(array('../controllers/', '_controller.php'), '', implode('|||', glob("../controllers/*_controller.php"))));
```

It's a bit dirty, but it gets the job done in a single line.

Comment: I like it, then it can be only two simple to remember lines: `$controllerlist = str_replace('../controllers/', '',  glob("../controllers/*_controller.php"));
$controllerlist = str_replace('_controller.php', '',  $controllerlist);`

Answer (score 1):

One command without searching and replacing? Yes you can!

If I'm not missing something grande, what about keeping it simple and chopping 15 characters from the start and the end using the substr function:

> substr ( $x , 15 , -15 )

Since glob will always give you strings with that pattern.

Example:

```
// test array (thanks FruityP)
$array = array(
    "../controllers/test_controller.php",
    "../controllers/hello_controller.php",
    "../controllers/user_controller.php" );

foreach($array as $x){ 
   $y=substr($x,15,-15); // Chop 15 characters from the start and end
   print("$y\n");
}
```

Output:

```
test
hello
user
```

Comment: can't you put that in one line with [`substr_replace`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php)?

Comment: This works: `$array = substr_replace(substr_replace($array,'',-15),'',0,15)`

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array like this :

```
$array = array(  "../controllers/*_controller.php", 
                  "../controllers/*_controller.php");
```

Then [array_map()](https://www.php.net/array_map) help you to trim the unnecessary string.

```
function trimmer( $string ){
    return str_replace( "../controllers/", "", $string );
 }
 $array = array(  "../controllers/*_controller.php", 
                  "../controllers/*_controller.php");

 print_r( array_map( "trimmer", $array  ) );
```

http://codepad.org/VO6kyVOa

Answer (score 0):

[preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) accepts an array as argument too:

```
$before = '../controllers/';
$after = "_controller.php";
$preg_str = preg_quote($before,"/").'(.*)'.preg_quote($after,"/");
$controllerlist = preg_replace('/^'.$preg_str.'$/', '\1',  glob("$before*$after"));
```

Answer (score 0):

to strip 15 chars at the start and 15 at the end of each arrayelement in one command:

```
$controllerlist = substr_replace(
     substr_replace(
          glob("../controllers/*_controller.php"),'',-15
          ),'',0,15
      )
```